# Angular-7 + Nativescript + Ionic-3 from one master project and share codes across them

Tags: angular, web, ionic3, nativescript, mobile-application

I want to ask about a concept and the best possible way to implement that.

I am going to create a project that will serve a web version using Angular 7 and mobile apps using nativescript and Ionic+cordova (differently).

I am going to create one master folder in which the three versions will be located. and each will share one common folder that I am going to manage by git submodule concept and it will have all common providers like auth services , master apis etc, and common components like Loader , alerts , toaster , and some http interceptors and error handlers.

I am seeking for any caveats / suggestions / risk factors of this approach and also any suggestion regarding the implementation.

Comment: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ may be the better place for these kind of questions

Comment: Are you saying that you want to create 2 mobile app versions one with Cordova and another with NativeScript?

Comment: Exactly @Manoj . One with Ionic + cordova , and another one with nativescript.

Comment: Would you mind disclosing why you may do that, developing the app twice in two different platforms?